# Automatically update Service Principal client secret on expiry?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-principal

I have a Service Principal for a Power Platform environment which will be used by a DevOps platform to make deployments to this environment.

The service principal requires me to set a client secret which will be referenced by my Service Connection in DevOps

[image]

You must set a client secret expiry date of up to 2 years and after that time, it won't work. So I would need to go into the Azure portal, update the client secret and then into DevOps and update the service connection.

Is there a way I can do this automatically?

Comment: This is called "secret rotation" You put the secret in KeyVault and make sure everything references it in there. Then on a regular schedule you generate a new secret and write it to keyvault. The old secret expires over time.

Comment: Allthough it looks like that paricualr screen has no UI to reference key vault, there might be an API that you can use.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - plus also, can you reference a key vault secret when setting a client secret in an app registration? I didn't seem to find it.

Comment: _when setting a client secret in an app registration_ I've never set a secret, only generated one. _ can you reference a key vault secret_ It depends on the "task" you are using some tasks provide a simple way to do this in a UI. Other tasks require you to write API code. With regards to key rotation, you first generate a new secret for the SP, capture it, and save that to the key vault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You must set a client secret expiry date of up to 2 years and after that time, it won't work.

Actually, no need to do that, in azure portal, the maximum is 2 years, but you could use azure powershell to create a near-permanent secret, e.g. 100 years.

If you want to custom the secret value, use [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.5.0) module, login with `Connect-AzAccount`, then use [`New-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-6.5.0) as below.

```
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId <ApplicationId of the App Registration> -CustomKeyIdentifier "test" -Password $SecureStringPassword -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(100)
```

[image]

If you want to generate a secret value automatically, use [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module, login with `Connect-AzureAD`, then use as [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) below.

```
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <ObjectId of the App Registration> -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(100)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there another way with the newer version of the API? How can I specify the Password with the newer version of the API?

Comment: You can no longer create secrets that are valid for more than 2 years.